# Not sure where to post a networking/NAS question

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question that pertains to networking and a Synology NAS. I'm not a network administrator, just the most tech savvy person at our small company. The question is mainly about an unusual network configuration on a Synology NAS.
Server Fault looked more advanced than this question but I couldn't find anything closer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Synology NAS is, as far as I know, mainly a consumer product. As such questions about these kind of products can be on-topic on [Super User](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic):

> Super User is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users

A quick search reveals [some related posts](https://superuser.com/search?q=Synology+NAS). If you're lucky you'll find your answer there or help you to bring the right focus to your question. Do check their help center and meta to verify if your actual question is indeed  a good fit.