# Where is the most appropriate place to ask a question about SMB sharing connection problem?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a problem about which I would like to ask for help. My question is about connecting SMB from a workstation to a Synology RS-820+ NAS server. Seven Windows 10 workstations share the resources, except one and only one. I work a lot of time on this problem, but I need help to further diagnose my problem. Server Fault and Super User sites have about 500 questions with the SMB tag, Stack Overflow half more. Where is the most appropriate place to ask such a question?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345215/not-sure-where-to-post-a-networking-nas-question but it looks like that NAS type you have is more a professional brand. Are you using this is a home-setup or is this is a professional enterprisy thing? In the latter case ServerFault might be applicable. However, if you expect it is a client-side issue I would start at Super User. Your question does need to have more details, like what settings you have on the NAS and any errors from the eventlog of the windows machine.